# How to change z-index of modal-backdrop indirectly?

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I need to change z-index of modal-backdrop class, but I don't want to change it directly like this:

```
 .modal-backdrop { z-index: 1090; }
```

since it is used in many places in application and I want to change it for single modal window. How to achieve that? My modal service looks like this:

```
angular.module('myModule').factory('modalFactory', function ($modal, $modalStack) {
        return {
            open: function () {
                $modal.open({
                    templateUrl: 'templates/modaltmp',
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    dialogFade: false,
                    keyboard: false,
                    controller: 'modalController as modalCtrl',
                });
            },
            close: function (reason) {
                $modalStack.dismissAll('close');
            }
        };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular has a setting for `backdropClass`, use it to add another class, then use that class to override with your own z-index:

```
    angular.module('myModule').factory('modalFactory', function ($modal, $modalStack) {
        return {
            open: function () {
                $modal.open({
                    templateUrl: 'templates/modaltmp',
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    backdropClass: 'foo',
                    dialogFade: false,
                    keyboard: false,
                    controller: 'modalController as modalCtrl',
                });
            },
            close: function (reason) {
                $modalStack.dismissAll('close');
            }
        };
    });
```

Then in your CSS:

```
.modal-backdrop.foo { z-index: 1090; }
```